# Kernel died when loading a dataset in Python: why does it happen?

Tags: python, scipy, dataset, spyder

I am trying to load a dataset of 7000 .mat files in Python as a 7000-d tensor with each entry of shape 100 x 100 x 100 x 3. The whole dataset is less than 80 MB. I am using Spyder. The code is as follows

```
dataDir = "/Users/..."
data= []
x_train = np.empty([7165, 100*100*100*3])
x_train = x_train.reshape([7165, 100, 100, 100, 3])

i = 0;

for file in sorted_alphanumeric(os.listdir( dataDir )):
    data = scipy.io.loadmat( dataDir+file )   #store data as LIST
    x_train[i] = np.array(data['tensor'])
    i = i + 1
```

However after about 2300 lines read, the kernel dies and the program stops running. Why does the kernel die? How can I store the dataset? It seems to me that the dataset is not that huge and the "Memory" key in the Console is always around 76%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not load the whole dataset at once to not run out of RAM. This cannot be avoided even on online tools such as Google Colab and dividing the datasets in multiple segments.
The way to deal with big datasets is via batch training (i.e. training the model by loading batches of the datasets at a time).

Answer (score 2):

7000x100x100x100 =7,000,000,000 is too much memory to handle even in **bits**
7 000 000 000 * 3 bits =
2.62500 gigabytes

Comment: but I am sure people deal with larger datasets? How can I load it on Python then?